# How to list files in users stage but not yours but other users?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, stage

I want to check if someone put sth into his users stage.
I would like to control it and need date of creation, date of modification, size, user etc.
Is there sth that I could use?

LIST @~

It only lists files of logged user.

As far as I know new user even without any role granted can PUT files in own user stage.
As an administrator I can just ask him "Pleeease, dont use it, its a very bad place for holiday photos, only you can view them" ;-)

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide us with what you have already tried for this question? This community would be helpful if you provide you own workaround and the things that didn't work! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be handy, but the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-create-stage.html#user-stages) say to not use user stages if multiple users need access.  It recommends named stages for that case.